SAS Modified Program Date/Time
There are multiple .sas programs saved in multiple folders on the SAS Server (Servers > SASApp > Home > Run 1 etc)
Is there a way I can check the last modified date for all of these programs at once? I know there is the dictionary.tables code but I think that's just for Libraries and not a filepath?
Also - is there a way to easily backup these programs?

Are you using some GUI interface that is showing you that filelist? Which one? SAS/Studio?  For SAS or for VIYA?  If it is normal SAS then you are just talking about files.  So any tool that can get directory information will work.  Such as https://github.com/sasutils/macros/blob/master/dirtree.sas

I'm using SAS Enterprise Guide 8.3.
The closest code I found is the below but it doesn't show modified date:
%let root_folder=/sasp/home/TEAM;
data work.sas_files;
infile "find &root_folder -type f -name ""*.sas"" -printf %nrstr('%h|%f\n')"  pipe end=done truncover dlm='|';
do until(done);
input path :$512. filename :$41.;
output;
end;
run;

If the goal is to just find information about files then you can use the FINFO() function. That will work assuming the path Enterprise Guide is showing you is available on the machine were SAS itself is running.
For example see this macro: https://github.com/sasutils/macros/blob/master/dirtree.sas
For example you could use this call
%dirtree(/sasp/home/TEAM,out=sas_files)

to make a dataset with every file in that directory tree.
You could then subset to the files of interest.  For example if you want the files that end with .sas you might do something like:
data sas_programs;
   set sas_files;
   where scan(filename,-1,'.') = 'sas';
run;


Perfect! Thanks!

Depending on the Linux version of your SAS host, you could use a different printf with your find
find ... -printf "%p %TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%TS %Tz\n"

